# Typo3 Easy way to add a new field to the text and images content element

Tags: element, addition, typo3, extend

Is there a easy way to just add a new form to a content element? Like I want an option selector where you can pick a color for the header.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the header_layout for that? You can customize  it in the page-TSConfig

Like this:

```
# change labels of existing header_layouts
TCEFORM.tt_content {
   header_layout.altLabels.0 = white
   header_layout.altLabels.1 = red
   header_layout.altLabels.2 = green
}

# add layouts
TCEFORM.tt_content{
   header_layout.addItems.4 = blue
   header_layout.addItems.5 = black
}

# remove layouts
TCEFORM.tt_content{
  header_layout.removeItems = 3
}
```

That's will then set a class to the layout-number, and you can style it with css.

If you actually need a separate field, that's a bit more involved.

Comment: this is great ; ) BUT i need the header layouts.. i would like to use header_position.. but unfortunately it does only add class="4" ..but i want it like class="white"

Comment: Doesn't this work:

  TCEFORM.tt_content.header_position.addItems.white = white

Comment: but I dont want to enhance the header_position field.

Comment: You said, one post before, that you wanted to use the header_position.

Comment: yes. that is correct. in your example you use the "header_layouts" field. which has an other function principle as the "header_position" field.

Comment: Yes, it has a different function, but customizing it should work in exactly the same way. So try

TCEFORM.tt_content.header_position.addItems.white = white